# Censor bleep keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, keyboard, software-recommendation, audio

I want the censor beep that you hear on TV to play continuously as a system sound when I hold down F12 on my MacBook.

I make screen recordings for YouTube videos. Because I have brothers and sisters that use profanity and I want to keep those moments out of my videos without further editing after I record them.

Is there a way to do this (assuming I am able to press the key fast enough of course)?

Comment: Are you recording your screen and need the key to play the noise internally or is this just you looking to turn your Mac external speaker into a soundboard just like if you had a horn or buzzer on your desk and the video recorder is an iPhone or other camera?

Comment: @bmike Need to play it as a system sound, so it will be part of my videos. I need it to play constantly when I hold down F12 and stop when I let go.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much no matter how loud you play it, the profanity will be audible to some extent. Plus, it's hard to predict when it's coming (which is why networks need to use 10-second delays when broadcasting live stuff). It's best to edit this in iMovie by detatching the audio and using the Split command before the offending word, then trimming the audio clip until the swear is out of your video. Then, drag your censor sound effect to the end of the first of your separated audio clips and trim that bleep to the start of the rest of your audio.

With this in mind, if the exact thing you requested in your question is what you want, you'll need to make a Service in Automator. First, open Automator, then create a Service in the next dialog. Find the `Run Shell Script` command and drag it into the drag-and-drop area. Copy-paste the text below into the text input area, replacing `completePathOfFile` with the path of your file:

`Afplay completePathOfFile`

Save this file and pick a memorable name.

Now go to System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > Services > Scroll to General. After finding the service you saved earlier, click the Add Shortcut button and type the F12 key. Hope this helps.